# Exception has occurred. _TypeError (type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>')

Tags: mysql, flutter, dart

I have problem with getruangfasiliti method. Is there any way to fix this error? I have been working this for weeks.

Tried this but it is not what i want.  I want to get the every data of the object

```
 Future<List> getruangfasiliti() async {
    final response = await http.get(BaseUrl.lihatruangfasiliti(widget.barcode));
    return jsonDecode(response.body);
  }
```

**So, below is my code and how i can fix the error. I do not know where my wrong is**

**modelAduan.dart**

```
class Aduan {
  final String aduan_id;
  final String tarikhaduan;
  final String ruang_id;
  final String fasiliti_id;
  final String maklumat;
  final String gambaraduan;
  final String status;
  final String idpengguna;
  final String namaruang;
  final String namafasiliti;

  Aduan({
    this.aduan_id,
    this.tarikhaduan,
    this.ruang_id,
    this.fasiliti_id,
    this.maklumat,
    this.gambaraduan,
    this.status,
    this.idpengguna,
    this.namaruang,
    this.namafasiliti
  });

  factory Aduan.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Aduan(
      aduan_id: json['aduan_id'],
      tarikhaduan: json['tarikhaduan'],
      ruang_id: json['ruang_id'],
      fasiliti_id: json['fasiliti_id'],
      maklumat: json['maklumat'],
      gambaraduan: json['gambaraduan'],
      status: json['status'],
      idpengguna: json['idpengguna'],
      namaruang: json['namaruang'],
      namafasiliti: json['namafasiliti'],
    );
  }
}
```

**aduan.dart**

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:eaduanfsktm/api.dart';
import 'package:eaduanfsktm/sejarahaduan.dart';
import 'package:fluttertoast/fluttertoast.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:eaduanfsktm/model/modelRuangFasiliti.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';
import 'dart:math' as Math;
import 'package:image/image.dart' as Img;
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:async/async.dart';
import 'package:path/path.dart';

class BorangAduan extends StatefulWidget {
  final String idpengguna, barcode;
  BorangAduan(this.idpengguna, this.barcode);
  @override
  _BorangAduanState createState() => _BorangAduanState();
}

class _BorangAduanState extends State<BorangAduan> {
  final _key = new GlobalKey<FormState>();
  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = new GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

  RuangFasiliti ruangfasiliti;

  TextEditingController controllerruang_id;
  TextEditingController controllerfasiliti_id;
  TextEditingController controller_namaruang;
  TextEditingController controller_namafasiliti;
  TextEditingController controllermaklumat = new TextEditingController();

  File _image;

  Future<RuangFasiliti> getruangfasiliti() async {
    final response = await http.get(BaseUrl.lihatruangfasiliti(widget.barcode));
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      setState(() {
        ruangfasiliti = RuangFasiliti.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body));
      });
      setState(() {
        controllerruang_id =
            new TextEditingController(text: "${ruangfasiliti.ruang_id}");
        controllerfasiliti_id =
            new TextEditingController(text: "${ruangfasiliti.fasiliti_id}");
        controller_namaruang =
            new TextEditingController(text: " ${ruangfasiliti.namaruang}");
        controller_namafasiliti =
            new TextEditingController(text: " ${ruangfasiliti.namafasiliti}");
      });

      return ruangfasiliti;
    }
  }

  // @override
  // void dispose() {
  //   controllerruang_id.dispose();
  //   controllerfasiliti_id.dispose();
  //   controller_namaruang.dispose();
  //   controllerruang_id.dispose();
  //   controller_namafasiliti.dispose();
  //   super.dispose();
  // }

  @override
  void initState() {
    getruangfasiliti();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        key: _scaffoldKey,
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Borang Aduan"),
        ),
        body: ListView(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
          children: <Widget>[
            FutureBuilder<RuangFasiliti>(
              future: getruangfasiliti(),
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.hasData) {
                  return aduanbox();
                } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                  return Text("${snapshot.error}");
                }
                return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
              },
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 10.0),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget aduanbox() {
    return Center(
      child: Form(
        key: _key,
        child: Card(
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                new Row(
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Expanded(
                      child: Container(
                        child: new TextFormField(
                          controller: controllerfasiliti_id,
                          readOnly: true,
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                            labelText: "KOD FASILITI",
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      flex: 2,
                    ),
                    SizedBox(width: 10.0),
                    Expanded(
                      child: Container(
                        child: new TextFormField(
                          controller: controller_namafasiliti,
                          readOnly: true,
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                            labelText: "NAMA FASILITI",
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      flex: 2,
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                new Row(
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Expanded(
                      child: Container(
                        child: new TextFormField(
                          controller: controllerruang_id,
                          readOnly: true,
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                            labelText: "KOD LOKASI",
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      flex: 2,
                    ),
                    SizedBox(width: 10.0),
                    Expanded(
                      child: Container(
                        child: new TextFormField(
                          controller: controller_namaruang,
                          readOnly: true,
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                            labelText: "LOKASI",
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      flex: 2,
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                TextFormField(
                  controller: controllermaklumat,
                  validator: (value) {
                    if (value.isEmpty) {
                      return 'Masukkan Maklumat Kerosakan';
                    }
                    return null;
                  },
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                      labelText: "MAKLUMAT",
                      hintText: "Masukkan maklumat kerosakan"),
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 10.0),
                Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    RaisedButton(
                      child: Icon(Icons.image),
                      onPressed: getImageGallery,
                    ),
                    SizedBox(width: 5.0),
                    RaisedButton(
                      child: Icon(Icons.camera_alt),
                      onPressed: getImageCamera,
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 10.0),
                Container(
                  alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                  child: _image == null
                      ? new Text("Tiada imej !")
                      : new Image.file(_image),
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 10.0),
                Container(
                  height: 45.0,
                  child: GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () {
                      if (_key.currentState.validate()) {
                        tambahaduan(_image);
                      }
                    },
                    child: Material(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                      color: Colors.blueAccent,
                      elevation: 7.0,
                      child: Center(
                        child: Text(
                          'HANTAR',
                          style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.white,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              fontFamily: 'Montserrat'),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Future getImageGallery() async {
    var imageFile = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);

    final tempDir = await getTemporaryDirectory();
    final path = tempDir.path;

    int rand = new Math.Random().nextInt(100000);

    Img.Image image = Img.decodeImage(imageFile.readAsBytesSync());
    Img.Image smallerImg = Img.copyResize(image, width: 500);

    var compressImg = new File("$path/image_$rand.jpg")
      ..writeAsBytesSync(Img.encodeJpg(smallerImg, quality: 85));

    setState(() {
      _image = compressImg;
    });
  }

  Future getImageCamera() async {
    var imageFile = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera);

    final tempDir = await getTemporaryDirectory();
    final path = tempDir.path;

    int rand = new Math.Random().nextInt(100000);

    Img.Image image = Img.decodeImage(imageFile.readAsBytesSync());
    Img.Image smallerImg = Img.copyResize(image, width: 500);

    var compressImg = new File("$path/image_$rand.jpg")
      ..writeAsBytesSync(Img.encodeJpg(smallerImg, quality: 85));

    setState(() {
      _image = compressImg;
    });
  }

  Future tambahaduan(File _image) async {
    var stream = new http.ByteStream(DelegatingStream.typed(_image.openRead()));
    var length = await _image.length();
    var uri = Uri.parse((BaseUrl.tambahaduan()));

    var request = new http.MultipartRequest("POST", uri);

    var multipartFile = new http.MultipartFile("aduanimages", stream, length,
        filename: basename(_image.path));
    request.fields['fasiliti_id'] = controllerfasiliti_id.text;
    request.fields['ruang_id'] = controllerruang_id.text;
    request.fields['maklumat'] = controllermaklumat.text;
    request.fields['idpengguna'] = widget.idpengguna;
    request.files.add(multipartFile);

    var response = await request.send();

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      print("Image Uploaded");
      setState(
        () {
          Fluttertoast.showToast(
            msg: "Aduan Berjaya",
            toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_LONG,
            gravity: ToastGravity.CENTER,
            backgroundColor: Colors.black,
            textColor: Colors.white,
            fontSize: 18.0,
          );
          Navigator.of(this.context).push(CupertinoPageRoute(
              builder: (BuildContext context) => SejarahAduan()));
        },
      );
    } else {
      print("Upload Failed");
    }
    response.stream.transform(utf8.decoder).listen((value) {
      print(value);
    });
  }
}
```

[this is my error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qsOHo.png)

Comment: Does the error says which line is your problem? I see you posted 2 functions with the same name. I believe RuangFasiliti.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body)) expects a Map<String, dynamic> but the jsonDecode(response.body) returns a List (for what I see in the first code Future<List> getruangfasiliti())

Comment: Can you share response json?

Comment: @EdwynZN  the first function i tried for the first time but it is not what i want, the error at the picture that i attach .

Comment: Yeah after seeing your error the problem is jsonDecode(response.body) return a List and you expect a Map to your RuangFasiliti.fromJson(). Change it to RuangFasiliti.fromJson((jsonDecode(response.body)).first) to use the first item of your list (probably a map) and the error should disappear

Comment: @EdwynZN yeah no error, but it return first item only. How do i get other value?

Comment: @EdwynZN from **widget.barcode**

Comment: @chikichikiboom this code is a mess; please provide returned JSON in response and learn to define variables with explicit types, this will help you understand where are the errors and why.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<RuangFasiliti> ruangfasiliti;

Future<RuangFasiliti> getruangfasiliti() async {
    final response = await http.get(BaseUrl.lihatruangfasiliti(widget.barcode));
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      var body = jsonDecode(response.body);
      setState(() {
        if(body is List) //check if it's a List
        ruangfasiliti = List<RuangFasiliti>.from(body.map(map) => RuangFasiliti.fromJson(map));
        if(body is Map) //check if it's a Map
        ruangfasiliti = [RuangFasiliti.fromJson(body)];
        controllerruang_id =
            new TextEditingController(text: "${ruangfasiliti.ruang_id}");
        controllerfasiliti_id =
            new TextEditingController(text: "${ruangfasiliti.fasiliti_id}");
        controller_namaruang =
            new TextEditingController(text: " ${ruangfasiliti.namaruang}");
        controller_namafasiliti =
            new TextEditingController(text: " ${ruangfasiliti.namafasiliti}");
      });

      return ruangfasiliti;
    }
  }
```

This code allows you to save a List ruangfasiliti, checks if the decoded json is a map or a list and saves it accordingly, but as the other comments said, you should provide and check the form of your JSON file to avoid this types of problems. If your JSON always returns a list it will be easy to just create a List body variable without checking the type of object